# Row-wise search for the values with minimum amplitude in a matrix

Tags: matlab, indexing

Given a vector, for example, `a=[1;1020;-1000;5;1040]`, my goal is to find another vector `b` such that for all `i`:

```
b[i] = a[i], if abs(a[i])<abs(a[i]+1024), abs(a[i])<abs(a[i]-1024),
b[i] = a[i]+1024, if abs(a[i]+1024)<abs(a[i]), abs(a[i]+1024)<abs(a[i]-1024)
b[i] = a[i]-1024, if abs(a[i]-1024)<abs(a[i]), abs(a[i]-1024)<abs(a[i]+1024)
```

The correct answer in the example is `b=[1,-4,24,5,16]`

I want a vectorized solution. I was trying to solve it by first constructing the following matrix: `temp=[a,a+1024,a-1024]`, then fiding indeces with minimum absolute value: `[~,ind]=min(abs(temp),[],2)`, and then applying the index: `b = temp (:,ind)`. The last statement does not work as I want it and I am not sure how to make it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify the math before starting to program, it helps a lot. According to your formula, 1024 is subtracted for all values above 512. 1024 is added for all values below -512. Makes some much simpler code:

```
b=a;
b(b>512)=b(b>512)-1024
b(b<-512)=b(b<-512)+1024
```

Answer (score 1):

ind is just the column index in a 2d array, you need to convert it to 1d index using `sub2ind`

this will get what you want.

```
b=temp(sub2ind(size(temp),(1:length(a)),ind'));
```